# How to define a function to get an field element of a Marshmallow Schema while still serialising through a nested Schema

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, schema, marshmallow

So I have a Nested Many Schema (eg `Users`) inside another Schema (eg `Computer`). My input object to be deserialised by the Schema is complex and does not allow for assignment, and to modify it to allow for assignment is impractical.

The input object (eg `ComputerObject`) itself does not contain an a value called "Users", but nested in a few other objects is a function that can get the users (eg `ComputerObject.OS.Accounts.getUsers()`), and I want the output of that function to be used as the value for that field in the schema.

Two possible solutions exist that I know of, I could either define the field as `field.Method(#call the function here)` or I could do a `@post_dump` function to call the function and add it to the final output JSON as it can provide both the initial object and the output JSON.

The issue with both of these is that it then doesn't serialise it through the nested Schema `Users`, which contains more nested Schemas and so on, it would just set that field to be equal to the return value of `getUsers`, which I don't want.

I have tried to define it in a `pre-dump` so that it can then be serialised in the dump (note: this schema is used only for dumping and not for loading), but as that takes in the initial object I cannot assign to it.

Basically, I have a thing I am trying to do, and a bunch of hacky workarounds that could make it work but not without breaking other things or missing out on the validation altogether, but no actual solution it seems, anybody know how to do this properly?

For further info, the object that is being input is a complex Django Model, which might give me some avenues Im not aware of, my Django experience is somewhat lacking.

Answer (score 0):

So figured this out myself eventually:

Instead of managing the data-getting in the main schema, you can define the method used in the sub-schema using post_dump with many=True, thus the following code would work correctly:

```
class User(Schema):
    id = fields.UUID

    @pre_dump(pass_many=True)
    def get_data(self, data, **kwargs):
        data = data.Accounts.getUsers()
        return data

class Computer(Schema):
    #The field will need to be called "OS" in order to correctly look in the "OS" attribute for further data
    OS = fields.Nested(User, many=True, data_key="users")
```